# How to count and sort repeating strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, hashset

i have got a string of names

```
String str = "A. Walker, L. Gordon, C. Riley, L. Gordon";
```

I need to count name occurancies and sort the occurancies from biggest to lowest.

I have done the countung part, but I also need to sort it.

```
String[] array = str.split(", ");        

List asList = Arrays.asList(array);
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(asList);
for(String s: mySet)
    System.out.println(s + " " +Collections.frequency(asList,s));
```

Output should look like this

```
L. Gordon 2, A. Walker 1, C. Riley 1
```

Comment: Use `LinkedHashSet` instead of `HashSet` to preserve insertion order, and sort `asList` before you pass it to the set. (Note, use `List<String> asList` rather than `List asList`).

Comment: And one way you can sort the list is with [java.util.Collections.sort( List<T> list )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-). If you need a special order, you can provide a Comparator<T> via similar methods in Collections and List.

Comment: Note that if you've sorted the list, you don't need to put them into a set...

Comment: Google: [`java count duplicates`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+count+duplicates).

Comment: If external libraries are allowed, Guava's `TreeMultiset` is the perfect ADT for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public class Test {
    static class NameFreq {
        public NameFreq(String name, int freq) {
            this.name = name;
            this.freq = freq;
        }
        String name;
        int freq;
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name + " " + freq;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String str = "A. Walker, L. Gordon, C. Riley, L. Gordon";
        Map<String, NameFreq> map = new HashMap<>();
        String[] array = str.split("\\s*,\\s*");
        for(String name : array) {
            NameFreq nameFreq = map.get(name);
            if( nameFreq==null )
                map.put(name, new NameFreq(name, 1));
            else
                nameFreq.freq++;
        }

        List<NameFreq> list = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<NameFreq>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(NameFreq o1, NameFreq o2) {
                return Integer.compare(o2.freq, o1.freq);
            }
        });

        System.out.println(list);
        //output: [L. Gordon 2, A. Walker 1, C. Riley 1]
    }
}
```

Comment: `new Integer(o2.freq).compareTo(o1.freq)` is unnecessarily boxing the `int` values. Use [`Integer.compare(o2.freq, o1.freq)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-) instead.

Comment: Although question doesn't specify a desired ordering of names with equal count, it would be common to require a secondary sort by name. This can be done by either changing the `HashMap` to a `TreeMap`, or by enhancing the `Comparator` with secondary comparison logic. For performance, the second option would be better.

Comment: @Andreas is right, **Integer.compare(i1, i2)** method is better than **new Integer(i1).compareTo(i2)**

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do it with `stream`, e.g.:

```
String str = "A. Walker, L. Gordon, C. Riley, L. Gordon";
TreeMap<String,Long> data = Arrays.stream(str.split(","))
    .map(s -> s.trim())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()));

LinkedHashMap<String,Long> resultMap= data.entrySet().stream()
```

.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue().reversed())
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
    System.out.println(resultMap);

If you want to strip out curly braces from the beginning and end of string, you can use `substring`, e.g.:

```
String result = resultMap.toString();
if(result.length > 2){
   result = result.substring(1, result.length() - 1);
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Nice use of groupingBy.

Comment: OP wants result sorted descending by count: *"sort the occurancies from biggest to lowest"*

Comment: @DarshanMehta `descendingMap()` is descending by *key* (name), not by *value* (count). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43282011/5221149) for sorting descending by count, and for building result string correctly (your current result is `A. Walker=1, C. Riley=1, L. Gordon=2`, not the requested `L. Gordon 2, A. Walker 1, C. Riley 1`).

Answer (score 2):

First, create a `Map`, keyed by name, with value being a count for that name. Then sort that descending by the value, secondary sort by key (aka name).

It seems you want result as a comma-separated string, so finally combine result that way.

Using Java 8 Streams, it can be done in a single method chain:

```
String str = "A. Walker, L. Gordon, C. Riley, L. Gordon";
String res = Pattern.compile(", *")
                    .splitAsStream(str)
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.<Entry<String, Long>, Long>comparing(Entry::getValue)
                                      .reversed()
                                      .thenComparing(Entry::getKey))
                    .map(e -> e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
System.out.println(res); // prints: L. Gordon 2, A. Walker 1, C. Riley 1
```

Notice the use of [`splitAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-), so the result of the split doesn't have to be stored in an intermediate array.

Comment: Isn't the code too complicate for this simple question?

Answer (score 1):

Use trie to count frequency, it saves a lot of space. And use heap to sort them. While pushing in trie you can count number of distinct words. Create heap of that size, max heap if you want to sort in ascending order.

Comment: If you want code as well, let me know. I will write it and post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution by [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
Stream.of(str.split(", "))
      .toMultiset()
      .toMapSortedByOccurrences(Comparators.reverseOrder());
```